# AWS Organization SCP to enforce encryption based on Bucket tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-organizations

I'm writing a SCP like below.

```html
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/Owner": [
            "finance"
          ]
        },
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
            "AES256",
            "aws:kms"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/Owner": [
            "finance"
          ]
        },
        "Null": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is to only allow users to upload files to buckets own by `finance` with using encryption.

I use Tag Key:Value `Owner:finance` to identify s3 buckets enforce this policy. However this, seems to be not working and still we can upload objects into these buckets without encryption.

Note, If I remove `aws:ResourceTag/Owner` condition, the policy works pretty well. But that affect all buckets. But in my case, I only need to apply this policy for the buckets, which owns by `finance` team.

Comment: The problem you have is that the tag refers to the object tags, not the bucket tags.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 is there any possibility you see to handle this?

Comment: Don't think it is possible.